# VB - cannot copy file due to "being used by another process" error

Tags: vb.net

I haven't been able to pinpoint exactly what is causing this error. All im trying to do is copy files (pdfs) that were created on the current day from 1 directory to another after a certain amount of time with the ticker. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

    Dim file As String
    Dim now As String = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString
    Dim dir As String = "C:\PDFs\"
    Dim bupdir As String = "C:\PDFs\copied\"
    Dim Files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(dir)

    For Each file In Files
        Dim dt As String = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file).ToShortDateString
        If dt = now Then
            IO.File.Copy(Path.Combine(dir, file), Path.Combine(bupdir, file), True)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Given that this is a timer, are the "ticks" overlapping? You may want to do a `Monitor.TryEnter` on a shared object on the tick to prevent it from stepping on itself.

Comment: @vcsjones I think it is a Windows Timer. Reentrancy should not be a problem

Comment: Please don't tag your question with languages you're not using...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that Directory.GetFiles() returns the full path name of the files in the source directory.

Then, when you try to build the destination file name, the `Path.Combine` sees that your `file` variable is an absolute path and doesn't add the path `bupdir`.
This gives back the value of the variable `file` and you end up with something like this

```
IO.File.Copy("C:\PDFs\file.pdf", "C:\PDFs\file.pdf", True)
```

To fix the problem

```
IO.File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(bupdir, Path.GetFileName(file)), True)
```

[FROM MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)

> If one of the specified paths is a zero-length string, this method
>   returns the other path. If path2 contains an absolute path, this
>   method returns path2.